# MySQL update query in CodeIgniter using where in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

I have to update my table data `where id in (1,2,3,4,5)`.

How can I implement this query in CodeIgniter?
What I have tried:

```
$id_list = '1,2,3,4,5';
$this->db->where_in('id', $id_list);
$this->db->update('my_table', $mydata);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Maybe check the manual? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `where_in`, you have to pass array. currently you are passing string. change your code as below:

```
$id_list = '1,2,3,4,5';
$id_list = explode(",",$id_list);
$this->db->where_in('id', $id_list);
$this->db->update('my_table', $mydata);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$id_list` should be an `array()` to work with `where_in`

Here is the code :

```
$id_list = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$this->db->where_in('id', $id_list);
$this->db->update('my_table', $mydata);
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html